# react-native - What should we do with file.snap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I am researching about testing using jest. Luckily, I am able to use jest for testing view.

However, I don't know how useful is the `tsx.snap` file. Below is the code:

```
exports[`renders correctly with defaults 1`] = `
<View
  style={
    Object {
      "alignItems": "center",
      "alignSelf": "center",
    }
  }
>
  <Text
    style={
      Object {
        "color": "#999",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
      }
    }
  >
    Hello

    World!
  </Text>
  <View
    style={
      Object {
        "alignItems": "stretch",
        "alignSelf": "center",
        "borderWidth": 5,
        "flexDirection": "row",
        "minHeight": 70,
      }
    }
  >
    <View
      style={
        Object {
          "flex": 1,
          "paddingVertical": 0,
        }
      }
    >
      <View
        accessibilityLabel="decrement"
        accessibilityRole="button"
        accessibilityStates={Array []}
        accessible={true}
        focusable={true}
        isTVSelectable={true}
        onClick={[Function]}
        onResponderGrant={[Function]}
        onResponderMove={[Function]}
        onResponderRelease={[Function]}
        onResponderTerminate={[Function]}
        onResponderTerminationRequest={[Function]}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={[Function]}
        style={
          Object {
            "opacity": 1,
          }
        }
      >
        <View
          style={
            Array [
              Object {},
            ]
          }
        >
          <Text
            style={
              Array [
                Object {
                  "color": "#007AFF",
                  "fontSize": 18,
                  "padding": 8,
                  "textAlign": "center",
                },
                Object {
                  "color": "red",
                },
              ]
            }
          >
            -
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View
      style={
        Object {
          "flex": 1,
          "paddingVertical": 0,
        }
      }
    >
      <View
        accessibilityLabel="increment"
        accessibilityRole="button"
        accessibilityStates={Array []}
        accessible={true}
        focusable={true}
        isTVSelectable={true}
        onClick={[Function]}
        onResponderGrant={[Function]}
        onResponderMove={[Function]}
        onResponderRelease={[Function]}
        onResponderTerminate={[Function]}
        onResponderTerminationRequest={[Function]}
        onStartShouldSetResponder={[Function]}
        style={
          Object {
            "opacity": 1,
          }
        }
      >
        <View
          style={
            Array [
              Object {},
            ]
          }
        >
          <Text
            style={
              Array [
                Object {
                  "color": "#007AFF",
                  "fontSize": 18,
                  "padding": 8,
                  "textAlign": "center",
                },
                Object {
                  "color": "blue",
                },
              ]
            }
          >
            +
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
`;
```

For me, this file is telling us the information of how styles are applied to our view.

If you know how useful the `tsx.snap` is, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!